# Is there any way to debug TensorFlow code? Also how can I see what's in the variables or objects while I interpret the code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

It's really easy to debug and track variable and object values as you run your Python code but in tensorflow, it's really hard to see what's going on behind the scene. I know tensorflow works in graphs and you have to run the session. Is there any simpler way to see the values as you interpret the code?  I have attached below screenshot where you can track every variable value but, in tensorflow I am unable to do that. I have tired a lot I have used tf.print() and tf.eval() in session.

[image: Pycharm Showing Variables Values]
Here is the code of tensorflow and I want to see values of **Z3** and **predict_op**

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate=0.01,


ops.reset_default_graph()  # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
tf.set_random_seed(1)  # to keep results consistent (tensorflow seed)
seed = 3  # to keep results consistent (numpy seed)
(m, n_H0, n_W0, n_C0) = X_train.shape
n_y = Y_train.shape[1]
costs = []  # To keep track of the cost

# Create Placeholders of the correct shape
X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0, n_C0, n_y)

# Initialize parameters
parameters = initialize_parameters()

# Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

# Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)


# Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer that minimizes the cost.

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initialize all the variables globally
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initialization
    sess.run(init)

    # Do the training loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        minibatch_cost = 0.
        num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size)  # number of minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set
        seed = seed + 1
        minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size, seed)

        for minibatch in minibatches:
            # Select a minibatch
            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
            # IMPORTANT: The line that runs the graph on a minibatch.
            # Run the session to execute the optimizer and the cost, the feedict should contain a minibatch for (X,Y).

            _, temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})


            minibatch_cost += temp_cost / num_minibatches

        # Print the cost every epoch
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
            print("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, minibatch_cost))
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 1 == 0:
            costs.append(minibatch_cost)



    # Calculate the correct predictions
    predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy on the test set
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print(accuracy)
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
    test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test})
    print("Train Accuracy:", train_accuracy)
    print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)

    return train_accuracy, test_accuracy, parameters
```

Comment: You may be looking for [`tensorboard`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz).

Comment: @FabienP Yes I know tensorboard but it's really complex. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try TensorFlow Eager Execution that allows you to run TensorFlow code directly without having to build a graph and run it during a session. It even says in the description that it enables easier debugging.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager

Comment: For future readers, as TensorFlow has moved with its 2.x version from the graph+session execution model, this is no longer valid. Now debugging is done the usual Python way.